# Sync Core Data to web server

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios6, synchronization

I developed an application which has a `Core Data`, now I am thinking to `Synchronize` it to my own `server`. and this is the first time I am doing it, I searched google a lot also StackOverflow but I couldn't find a clear approach to work on.

I have created the same `core data` on the `server`, but I don't know how to know if some row has been `synced` or not (how to arrange connection between the `server` and the `Client`), should I add another column to the `core data` as `boolean` to tell me the `sync status`?!! or by adding a `timestamp`?!!.. so please if anyone can help me with that or know how to do it, tell me!!
I need help with logic. and I am using `REST API` `(POST,GET)` methods.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at using [RestKit](http://restkit.org) to help you with the communication with the server.

Yes, you will want to add some additional data to allow you to determine if the data has been edited since it was last synched with the server. A `BOOL` should be sufficient for this, just set it when any other attribute is changed (you can use KVO to assist with this).

You will need to create and control the logic for which updates are sent back to the server and when. If you post the individual object then RestKit could respond and automatically set the `BOOL` back to false for you (but whether you want to do that depends very much on how many objects are changing, how often and how big they are - you don't want to make lots of frequent small updates to the server).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Have an extra column in Core Data called isSynced - this is set to false if it's updated, then make a call to the server and attempt to update.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I blogged about syncing ([sync algorithm for exchanging data in the “Client – Server” model via REST API](http://havrl.blogspot.ie/2013/08/synchronization-algorithm-for.html)). It might help you to get some ideas with building the sync logic for your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently in one of my apps. In brief, what you should know is that your "Attributes" of the entities should be treated as separate columns where in the table name can be same as the "Entity Name". After that if you need to sync the data, it can be done by setting the data in the header of the API which can be retrieved on the server side.

e.g: Suppose there is an entity named PlaylistData with attributes playlist_name and songs in it. Same is the column name on server side. Now you want to save these on the server.
First you save your data in a playlistNameArray and songs in songArray.
After that -

```
NSString *api = [NSString stringWithFormat:SAVE_PLAYLIST_API,id1];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:api] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableDictionary *requestDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[requestDict setObject:self.playlistName forKey:@"playlist_name"];
[requestDict setObject:songIdArray forKey:@"songs"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestDict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
NSString *jsonStr =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

id response = nil;
NSError *error1 = nil;
NSData *recievedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error1];

NSString *dataReceived =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:recievedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error2 = nil;
```

// You can see the "recievedData" to review the response from server.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these resources:
http://iphone2009.crowdvine.com/talk/presentation_file/5104/Grover_Syncing.pdf
http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1